# pine script series manipulation

Tags: indexing, series, pine-script

I made a lot of changes to the code. It is as follows:

```
//@version=4
study("Doubt",overlay=true)
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © m1akitak1r

tf = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval ="current")
up = high[2]<high[1] and high[0]<high[1]
down = low[2]>low[1] and low[0]>low[1] 

lows=0.0
highs=0.0
highs:=up?high[1]:na
lows:=down?low[1]:na
lowLocations=down?bar_index:na//[1]
highLocations=up?bar_index:na//SPHBars[0]
pivots= up?high[1]:down?low[1]:na
plot(pivots, "pivots", color=color.lime, linewidth=7, style=plot.style_circles, transp=0, offset=-1, join=true)
```

When it is executed the sample result is like this

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtKKC.png)

It essentially connects the highs and lows detected above. The highs and lows are some sort of pivots. The highs and lows should be alternating meaning a low should exist between two highs and a high should exist between two lows. But as can be seen there are places where there are multiple highs between two lows and multiple lows between two highs. The code should be modified such that wherever there are multiple highs between two lows, the highest high of those multiple highs only should be retained and wherever there are multiple lows between two highs, the lowest of those multiple lows only should be retained. The final required connection should be as marked drawn manually [I have marked the red lines manually where multiple highs and lows need to be eliminated where as the other alternating high lows should not be affected]. The correct alternating high and low locations should be stored in lowLocations and highLocations.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is not clear but I think what you're looking for is this..

```
if(crossunder(close,localminima)
    //do something
```

Note that you cannot have conditional plots, that means you cannot call `plot()` inside of an `if() condition`

Comment: LL is a series that contains the local miniima. It looks like this [.........15, followed by few na  1followed by a few na,,2,few na,3,few na, 1.5, few ]. The spacing or bars between non na values is not uniform. Now what I need is to find the lowest Local minima which in this case 1. if you observe it correctly 3>1.5=>marks the start of a new period and the lowest is 1, the lowest among 1,2,3. and 15 starts a new series as 15>1. so from 15 it marks the beginning of a new period for which I need to find a new low again.

Comment: I think that this will help you https://backtest-rookies.com/2018/04/06/tradingview-track-when-something-happened/